# Error en Sequelize con formato de fecha

Tags: javascript, nodejs, sequelize.js

El error lo tira un segmento de Sequelize pero no sé porqué, dado que el string con la fecha parece estar correctamente formateado.

Las líneas que generan el error deben ser las siguientes, supongo:

```javascript
            const now = new Date();
            
            const time = `${now.getFullYear()}-${now.getMonth() + 1}-${now.getDate()} ${now.getHours()}:${now.getMinutes()}:${now.getSeconds()}`;

            try{
                sale_product = await db.Sale_Product.create({saleTime:time,saleBusiness:business.id,productid:product.id,sold:Number(req.body.saleItems[i].quantity)})

    code: 'ER_WARN_DATA_TRUNCATED',
    errno: 1265,
    sqlState: '01000',
    sqlMessage: "Data truncated for column 'saleTime' at row 1",
    sql: 'INSERT INTO `sale_product` (`saleTime`,`saleBusiness`,`productid`,`sold`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);',
    parameters: [
      '2023-09-14 23:20:35',
      9,
      10,
      1,
      '2023-09-14 23:20:35',
      '2023-09-14 23:20:35'
    ]
  },
```

```sql
  sql: 'INSERT INTO `sale_product` (`saleTime`,`saleBusiness`,`productid`,`sold`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);',
  parameters: [
    '2023-09-14 23:20:35',
    9,
    10,
    1,
    '2023-09-14 23:20:35',
    '2023-09-14 23:20:35'
  ]
}
```

Comment: `Data truncated for column 'saleTime' at row 1` NO es un error, es una advertencia, sugiere que en la BD lo que estas añadiendo como fecha no tiene un tamaño adecuado, y por ende los datos estan siendo truncados, es decir, puede que literalmente si te inserte la fecha, pero no te la esta insertando completa, la solucion es cambiar el tipo de dato de la BD a uno que soporte la fecha que estas intentando insertar, que en este caso NO debe ser un `DATE` sino un `DATETIME` o `TIMESTAMP`.